# Next.js 13 og image not working when I put it in app directory

Tags: next.js, next.js13

"I read the documentation, which states to add an opengraph-image.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) image file to any route segment.
I placed my opengraph-image.png in the root directory of my app, but after building it, it didn't generate the og image tag for me. Any ideas?
[image]

I hope it can generated og image tag for me in index.html

Comment: yes, I solve it by add my website address in my meta config object. It can't be localhost

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solve this by add metadataBase in metadata

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Next Dashboard",
  description: "Dashboard wrote in Next.js",
  metadataBase: new URL("https://next-dashboard.pinkjelly.org/"),
};
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could clarify which specific page or image you are referring to with the link "https://next-dashboard.pinkjelly.org/". Thank you for your help and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The file structure seems correct. You could check that:

- Not setting the `image` field in any `metadata` variable export.
- Not setting the `image` field in any `generateMetadata` function export.
- You are in a version of Next.js 13 that supports `opengraph-image` metadata files.

To verify if it's working, you could run the app and check the metadata in the page `head` HTML element if the solution worked. You should see something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<generated>" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="<generated>" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="<generated>" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="<generated>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue as you in my Next.js app that was built with the App Directory architecture.

On Vercel having the `opengraph-image.png` file in my route worked. However, on Netlify, this did not work.

On Netlify, I could only get my image working by exporting the `metatdata` object in my root `layout.tsx` file.

I put two small write-ups together documenting this strange behavior that I found:

[Static Open Graph Image for Next.js Netlify](https://thetombomb.com/posts/og-image-nextjs-netlify)

[Static Open Graph Image for Next.js Vercel](https://thetombomb.com/posts/og-image-nextjs-vercel)

Answer (score 0):

add your image in the public folder and:

```js
import image from '../../../public/image_open_graph.png';

(...)

 openGraph: {
      title: titlePage,
      description: descriptionPage,
      images: [
        {
          url: image.src,
        },
      ],
    },
    
(...)
```

And ready!

Answer (score 0):

`next 14.0.4` and the following worked!

```
import ogImage from './opengraph-image.jpg'
...
export const metadata = {
  ...
  metadataBase: new URL("https://yourWebUrl.com"),
  openGraph: {
    ...
    images: [
      {
        url: ogImage.src,
        width: ogImage.width,
        height: ogImage.height
      },
    ],
  },
  twitter: {
    images: [
      {
        url: ogImage.src,
        width: ogImage.width,
        height: ogImage.height
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Your image must be served by your server. You should put it inside the public folder and put the url in the og image tag.